# Silverlight tests not working unless RDP connection open

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, white-framework

I have a few Silverlight UI tests that I'm automating with White.  These tests are subsequently run by a TFS build agent, which is running interactively so it can access the desktop.

The build passes if I have a Remote Desktop connection open to the build agent as the tests are run; I can see the mouse pointer moving around.  When the test clicks on a HyperlinkButton navigation takes place, and is subsequently verified by assertions within the test.

The build fails if I do not have a Remote Desktop connection open to the build agent as the tests are run.  The Internet Explorer window is created and the Silverlight app loads, but no clicks happen; the application remains on the initial page and test assertions subsequently fail.

Has anyone out there found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Starting a Windows service in an interactive session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897568/starting-a-windows-service-in-an-interactive-session)

If you are setting up a windows service, that service can be set to run with an interactive desktop, though it will be running as a local machine user and not a domain user.

The other alternative is tweaking the registry to use the AutoAdminLogon feature. Use with caution!

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon:

- DefaultUsername
- DefaultPassword
- DefaultDomain
- AutoAdminLogon = 1

Comment: I'll use AutoAdminLogon, I think.  The machine in question is a well-segregated VM that's used solely for building and testing within the development environment.

I tried setting up the service to interact with the desktop, but that isn't enough; while the service could then create windows, White was still unable to interact with them without an active session.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on [this CodePlex thread](http://white.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=207089). Basically there is no solution; White tests must be run by a logged-in user (either physically, or via VNC or RDP).