# How to integrate Rational Functional Tester(RFT) and Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, rft

As part of our continuous integration and testing,we could like to execute a set of RFT automated tests after each build and unit test is complete. If anyone has done this before,please provide the instructions for the same.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hudson and rational functional tester](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914009/hudson-and-rational-functional-tester)

Answer (score 1):

Some Web resources on the topic:

- Someone actually tried the same:
  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=cda9f004-65bd-4594-b987-cfca4174ba9b
- How to set up head less UI testing (you need to somehow get the OS
  support for UI testing):
  http://rapaul.com/2011/06/05/zero-to-headless-browser-tests-jenkins/
- How to run RFT from Command line: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/is-it-possible-create-integration-3768419.S.219369876

This should give you a start. Your goal is to set up a system where you can run the tests as a real user (from an OS point of view) and not as a service.